# Unable to display image

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

When I try to execute my application all the data's in the database are getting displayed and instead of storing image I stored its path in DB and displaying the image but when I render it in chrome it says

> Error: 404 not found

But when I check it physically the images are present in folder where I uploaded.

**Screenshot:**

[image: screenshot of my output]

**EmpdetController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadFile()
    {
        var file = Request.Files[0];
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Photos"), file.FileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);

        // prepare a relative path to be stored in the database and used to display later on.
        var filename = path;
        // save to db
        return Json(filename.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

**EmpdetList:**

```
<h2>EmpdetList</h2>

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" ng- table="tableParams" show-filter="true">
<tr ng-repeat="Empdet in EmpdetList">                       
    <td data-title="'Id'" filter="{ 'Id': 'text' }" sortable="'Id'">{{Empdet.Id}}</td>
    <td data-title="'FirstName'" sortable="'FirstName'" filter="{ 'FirstName': 'text' }">{{Empdet.FirstName}}</td>
    <td data-title="'LastName'" sortable="'LastName'" filter="{ 'LastName': 'text' }" >{{Empdet.LastName}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Email'" sortable="'Email'" filter="{ 'Email': 'text' }">{{Empdet.Email}}</td>
    <td data-title="'PhotoText'" sortable="'PhotoText'" filter="{ 'PhotoText': 'text' }"><img ng-src={{Empdet.PhotoText}} class="img-responsive"/></td>
    <td data-title="'Age'" sortable="'Age'" filter="{ 'Age': 'text' }">{{Empdet.Age}}</td>

    <td data-title="'Action'">
        <div data-toggle="modal" data-id="{{Empdet.Id}}" data-index="{{$index}}" data-name="{{Empdet.Id}}" ng-click="DeleteEmployee(Empdet.Id)"  title='Click to delete the Account' class="open-confirm-delete fa fa-trash-o deleterow" style="height: 24px!important;">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can you give path of image and path of your application? or try `Server.MapPath(@"~/Photos")`

Comment: Image path: "C:\\Users\\kaviarasuk\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\MyEmployee\\MyEmployee\\Photos\\riki.jpg"

Comment: its the image path i m getting through json once the image is uploaded

Comment: See my answer. You can't refer to physical image paths on your harddrive for images. They must be relative to the server URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You returned the absolute `path` (`C:/...`) of the image on file system.

You have to return the relative path of the image to the server. Because you want the path to be `/Photos/image.png`.

```
var filename = Url.Content("~/Photos/" + file.FileName);
```

The code will change like below.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFile()
{
    var file = Request.Files[0];
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Photos"), file.FileName);
    file.SaveAs(path);

    // prepare a relative path to be stored in the database and used to display later on.
    var filename = Url.Content("~/Photos/" + file.FileName);
    // save to db
    return Json(filename.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

Comment: He doesn't return a relative path, that's the point. He returns the full path of the file.

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen thank you for correcting me, I was confused with relative and absolute path.

Comment: Also, it seems like you need an additional `/` before appending `file.FileName` to the path right?

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen You have hawk eyes :)

Comment: Thank you very much guys for correcting my mistakes and just now i started learning this i m not that much good with soon i will try to learn a lot .. thanks once again

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen (Error: http://localhost:1256/Empdet/%22/Photos/jug.jpg%22) i m still getting this error not found 404 aft changing to relative path as u said in the before comment.

Comment: @Frankline check your js code. You have unnecessary `"` in the path of your image, when you construct it. (`http://localhost:1256/Empdet/%22/Photos/jug.jpg%22` should be `http://localhost:1256/Empdet/Photos/jug.jpg`)

Comment: @adricadar sry for asking this how u mark that double quotes in a ash color so that i can highlight my errors

Comment: you use the key above the Tab on your keyboard ` code `. This uses the Markdown syntax. For more info check here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: @adricadar should i check in my controller or in views file

Answer (score 1):

The code seems to refer to path names of the images with double slashes (`//`) in them (see your own Chrome screenshot). See if removing these helps.

Furthermore, it seems that each path of the image starts with a proper URL to `localhost` but then has a full file path appended to it, starting with `C:\`, which suggests that you need to append relative paths instead.

Like I described to you in a comment to your question, you can't refer to absolute paths on your server from a web based project. You need to refer to relative paths from the root URL.

Comment: i am new to this asp.net and angularjs but i dont know how to remove that double slashes (//) can u help me

Comment: The internet is your friend. There is plenty of documentation online. StackOverflow is not a "write-my-code-for-me" community for trivial problems.

Answer (score -1):

Either you should store a virtual path instead of physical or otherwise if you want to store a physical path then you should convert physical path to hosting path.

You can use this code:

```
public static class PathExtensions
{


    public static string ToVirtual (this string physicalPath)
    {
        string url=physicalPath.Substring(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/");).Replace('\\', '/').Insert(0, "~/Photos/");
        return (url);
    }
}
```

Then you can call this extension method before you can send your list back.

```
yourlist.ForEach( item => item.url = item.url.ToVirtual());
```

**There will be performance hit. However, this code will take you further**

Comment: This screams bad practice and is a horrible solution by all means (no offense to you as a person).

Comment: have you seen the screen shot? He is sending a physical path at client side, I am asking him to send a relative one if he has not saved it. So why the hack it is horrible??

Comment: Okay. Let's summarize. Excessive use of extension methods (why extend `string` for this very specific problem?). Accessing the `HostingEnvironment` from a Singleton-like structure, making it impossible to test, and prone to errors when used outside of the web context. Use of `Replace` function to fiddle with path structures, opening the possibility for Path Traversal vulnerabilities. And finally, the most important one... **Treating the symptoms, not fixing the problem**. I hope you know all this already. Every developer should.

Comment: Even the fact that you called it a *hack* and still accept it as a viable solution, when the real solution is so simple, is not very good. Oh, and finally... **Your code does not compile**.